# Autoscroll in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

It's possible to perform autoscroll when I add value to a cell below last visible row on form?
I cannot find any autoscroll properties in DataGridView. Is the only possible way to do this to find index of the last visible cell and change FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `FirstDisplayedCell` property to make that cell displayed.
Since you know which cell you added the value to, you can do it like this:

```
dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedCell = yourCell
```

Comment: Thanks, it's more handy. But how to determine which cell is visible on the screen, and which - no?

Answer (score 1):

Can try this,

```
gv.FirstDisplayedCell = gv.Rows[gv.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

These 3 lines are really equivalent to an auto scroll down

```
System.Int16 i_NotDisplayableRowCount = dataGridView1.RowCount - dataGridView1.DisplayedRowCount(false); // false means partial rows are not taken into acount
if (i_NotDisplayableRowCount > 0)
    dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i_NotDisplayableRowCount;
```